# ResXResourceWriter method replaces the entire ResX file

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, resources, resx

I'm trying to write a method that should add a resource to an ResX file, the resource is added but the other resources contained in the ResX file are lost, I think that the file is replaced by a new one with only the resource that I added.

PS: I've taken the example from [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.resources.resxresourceset).

What I'm doing wrong and What changes I need to do in my method to fix this?

```
''' <summary>
''' Adds a resource inside a ResX resource table.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ResXFile">Indicates the ResX file to add the resource.</param>
''' <exception cref="System.Exception"></exception>
Private Sub AddResXResource(ByVal ResXFile As String,
                            ByVal ResourceName As String,
                            ByVal Resource As Object,
                            Optional ByVal Comment As String = Nothing)

    If Not IO.File.Exists(ResXFile) Then
        Throw New Exception(String.Format("Resource file: '{0}' not found.", ResXFile))

    Else

        ' Open the existent ResX file.
        Using ResXWritter As New Resources.ResXResourceWriter(ResXFile)

            ResXWritter.AddResource(New Resources.ResXDataNode(ResourceName, Resource) _
                                        With {.Name = ResourceName, .Comment = Comment})
            ResXWritter.Generate()

        End Using ' ResXWritter As New Resources.ResXResourceWriter(ResXFile)

    End If ' Not IO.File.Exists(ResXFile)

End Sub
```

This is how I'm using the method:

```
Dim MyResource As Bitmap = SystemIcons.Information.ToBitmap
AddResXResource(".\Resources.resx", "SysIcon_Info", MyResource, "Resource comment")
```

Comment: Seem like you are just using a ResX writer over a filename. I think you need to use the ResXResourceSet, load the existing resources, get a writer from the set, use the writer to add your new entry, generate the new resource.

Comment: @Marvin Smit thanks for comment, do you mean to?: 1. retrieve all the existent resources in the file, 2. add them all again in the file (this should replace the existent file, but I'm adding all the retrieved resources from the original file) and finally 3. add the new one resource in that file?. I've suppossed that these Classes would facilitate that task.

Comment: 1: Yes, read them into a resourceset. 2: no, no need to copy. 3: get a writer from the resourceset instance. Then use your formentioned code.

Comment: hmmm but the constructor of the writter doesn't accept me a resourceset, I think that I've don't understood the '3' step.

Comment: ResourceSet.GetDefaultWriter()

Comment: That returns a Type, I don't know how to continue, sorry, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is what I'm doing (retrieve the existent resources to copy them again in the specified file together with the new one resource), but I don't consider this a consistent solution so `I would like to mark as accepted a solution that avoids the copying of the original resources`, I really suppose that one of the provided ResX Classes/methods should do that task.

The code:

```
' Add ResX Resource
' ( By Elektro )
'
' Usage Examples:
' AddResXResource(".\Resources.resx", "Bitmap Resource", SystemIcons.Information.ToBitmap, "Resource Comment")
'
''' <summary>
''' Adds a resource inside a ResX resource table.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ResXFile">Indicates the ResX file to add the resource.</param>
''' <exception cref="System.Exception"></exception>
Private Sub AddResXResource(ByVal ResXFile As String,
                            ByVal ResourceName As String,
                            ByVal Resource As Object,
                            Optional ByVal Comment As String = Nothing)

    Dim [Resources] As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    If Not IO.File.Exists(ResXFile) Then
        Throw New Exception(String.Format("Resource file: '{0}' not found.", ResXFile))

    Else

        ' Open the existent ResX file.
        Dim ResX = New Resources.ResXResourceSet(ResXFile)

        ' Get the resource enumerator.
        Dim ResXDictionay As IDictionaryEnumerator = ResX.GetEnumerator()

        ' Loop through the existing resources to copy them in the collection.
        Do While ResXDictionay.MoveNext()
            Resources.Add(CStr(ResXDictionay.Key), ResXDictionay.Value)
        Loop ' ResXDictionay.MoveNext()

        ' Add the resource(s) in the ResX file.
        ' Note: This will replace the existent file.
        Using ResXWritter As New Resources.ResXResourceWriter(ResXFile)

            ' Add the retrieved resources into the ResX file.
            If [Resources] IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each ResourceItem In [Resources]
                    ResXWritter.AddResource(ResourceItem.Key, ResourceItem.Value)
                Next ResourceItem
            End If

            ' Add the specified resource into the ResX file.
            ResXWritter.AddResource(New Resources.ResXDataNode(ResourceName, Resource) _
                                        With {.Name = ResourceName, .Comment = Comment})
            ResXWritter.Generate()

        End Using ' ResXWritter As New Resources.ResXResourceWriter(ResXFile)

    End If ' Not IO.File.Exists(ResXFile)

    [Resources] = Nothing

End Sub
```